# Git rebase -Xtheirs keep entire file instead of specific conflicting part

Tags: git

How can I achieve the same as:

```
git rebase -Xtheirs <commit hash>
```

but keeping the my entire file instead of just the conflicting part?

For more context: If I don't keep the entire file sometimes the code is missing for example a closing bracket that was lost in picking my change but the opening one is still introduced by the commit I rebase on in a non conflicting part of the file. Also the commit I'm trying to rebase on is only a formatting commit, so it's ok to discard the entire file.

Comment: Why not just resolve conflicts manually? It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

It's rarely worth trying to automate this.  Just let `git rebase` do its thing, and when you hit a conflict and the rebase pauses, use:

```
git checkout --theirs path/to/conflicted/file
git add path/to/conflicted/file
git rebase --continue
```

You *can* automate this somewhat, using `git status --porcelain` or `git status --porcelain=v2` to drive a script that does the `git checkout` + `git add`, but you can't get Git to run this script for you as it pauses each conflicted rebase commit-copy.

You *could* use your own manual series of `git cherry-pick` commands to implement the rebase, running them from your own script.  Then you could automate the entire process.  That's probably not wise though: it will blindly apply this rule to cases where it's inappropriate.